# Manual aggregate in python

Tags: python, aggregate, data-analysis

I have a list of tuples like

```
[
    (A,B,C,D,E,..., value),
    ...
]
```

where `A, B, C...` are integers or short strings. The size of each tuple is the same across the list (~10 fields)

List has about 50000 tuples.

In UI user can specify a value for each `A, B, C...` field or leave the field blank, which means that it can have any value.

The output should contain all the matching tuples from the list and the aggregation of `value` (sum or average)

What is the fastest and pythonic way to achieve this?

(The list is read from the database via ORM, but there are a lot of in-app calculations, so `A,B,C...` fields are not directly mapped to the database columns)

Or should I reorganize the list?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. I have no idea whether its the fastest (does it really matter?) or the most Pythonic (not sure what the word means any more), but I do like the general strategy, which is to define a function or lambda that knows how to evaluate each data item and return true if it should be retained.

```
data = [
    (1, 2, 3),
    ('a', 2, 3),
    (1, 'c', 4),
    (1, 'd', 4),
]

criteria = (1, None, 4)

f    = lambda tup: all(t == c or c is None for t, c in zip(tup, criteria))
keep = filter(f, data)
```